# Overwriting File if File already exists

Tags: php

I have code I'm using to create a file using the name of one field, then opening that file and writing the contents from another. That works fine.

However when users attempt to pull up this file and change information and save it it doesn't overwrite the information.

If a user deletes the file (which works) then recreates it using the same name, but attempts to input new data, it creates the new file (with the same name as the old file) however it retains the old information and doesn't update. I can't find out what's causing that.

I was originally using file_put_contents and I've attempted to use different parameters for the fopen() but it doesn't seem to work. They can create and save just fine, however the main issues are they can't edit as it doesn't overwrite data and they can't delete the file (even as a workaround) and recreate it using the same name.

**edited to add:** Also when they try and save information, instead of opening the file and overwriting it, it creates a second and NEW file filename.html.html

```
//  Put together the full path of the file we want to create
$FILENAME = $USER_DIRECTORY.'/'.$_POST['CodeDescription'].'.html';
$CODE = $_POST['Code'];
if( !is_file( $FILENAME ) ):

  // Open the text file, write the contents, and close it.
    $fp = fopen($FILENAME, "w+") or die("Couldn't open $FILENAME for 
writing!");
    fwrite($fp, $CODE) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 
endif;
header('Location: mywebsite.comsaved=1&file='.$FILENAME);
}
?>
```

Comment: whats are the file permissions on a created file?

Comment: They're currently set to 644 on those create files.

Comment: You need to use flags for it file put contents has FILE_APPEND  see  flags section http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: `chmod` the files to `0664` and try again?

Comment: Your code specifically checks that the file exists first and only proceeds if it doesn't (`!is_file( $FILENAME )`) - so yes, the code you posted will never overwrite an existing file? Your `Location` header also seems to be malformed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what Im missing or getting with the flags.

chmodding doesn't change anything. The file actually updates, if they delete it and re-create it, however attempting to overwrite the file just creates a new one with filename.html.html

@w3dk trying to fix that part now, and the header takes them back to the same page just with the name of the file after its saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hack might be to try this:

```
//  Put together the full path of the file we want to create
$FILENAME = $USER_DIRECTORY.'/'.$_POST['CodeDescription'].'.html';
$CODE = $_POST['Code'];

//Delete file if exists.
if(is_file( $FILENAME)) {
    unlink($FILENAME);
}

  // Open the text file, write the contents, and close it.
    $fp = fopen($FILENAME, "w+") or die("Couldn't open $FILENAME for 
writing!");
    fwrite($fp, $CODE) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 
header('Location: mywebsite.comsaved=1&file='.$FILENAME);
}
```